# How to use a method as an argument of another method when they have different types in java?

Tags: methods, types, arguments

I need to add a method inside this add(null) method but the method has a string argument like the following

```
private double mymethod(String writing) // This is the method which must replace  
                                  // the null value inside the add(null) method
```

but since it has a String argument this gives an error! what could i do in order to fix this problem?

Comment: I don't userstand what you want to achieve. You certainly cannot have nested methods...

Comment: Could you elaborate on your goal?

Comment: features.add(mymethod(writing)); this is what i want or sth like this!!???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you have I think that **features** is a Collection of Doubles - is that right?

And what you want to do is the following:

```
features.add(mymethod("some string"));
```

If thats the case I dont see the problem I'm afraid - where is the error being thrown?

Provided your **mymethod** returns a valid **double** I cant see what else would cause you a problem here.

Comment: That's right , you have understood my question properly. However i did not put quotes different than your solution and now it seems correct! Thanks a lot.